# Accessing numerical property in a json object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a PHP multidimensional array witch i converted to JSON using JSON_encode().

I am using drupal so for those not familiar with it, drupal array often have keys that looks like that :

```
$some_array['und']['0']['value']
```

So my JSON object ends up looking like:

```
some_array.und.0.value
```

Now the problem is that when use the above syntaxe to retreive the value i the following JS error in the FB console : **"missing name after . operator"**

Also this data is meant to be used with a Jquery template, so i alos tried accessing this data directly in my template with:

```
${field_city.und.0.value}
```

Witch unfortunately didn't work either..

How would i go to fix that issue ? Can i access somehow this proprety with JS? Or is there a way that i have JSON_encode function replace all 0 by let's say "zero"? Or even replacing '0' when parsing the JSON string?

Suggestions much appreicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as using the dot notation, you can use regular array notation to access JSON nodes:

```
some_array.und['0'].value
```

Comment: Thanks alex for your answer, i ll give this some more testing and kudos you.

Answer (score 3):

Try accessing it with some_array.und["0"].value.   '0' is not a valid name for a javascript object, which is why accessing it via the . notation is not working. 
However, if you access it via the square brackets, you can access keys with any name at all.